# Form boolean attribute won't change value after submission

Tags: python, django

I was building a form for file uploads that is only visible to a student type of account. And I wanted that after the student submits the form, it will not show a second time, so in my Student model I used a boolean for that. After submission it will become true and the form should not appear again. Problem is, the boolean doesn't change value, so I think there is something wrong with the view.

```js
class StudentFileUpload(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey("Course", related_name='files', on_delete=None, default=None)
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='student_files', null=True, blank=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField('courses.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, blank=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.files)

    def file_link(self):
        if self.files:
            return "<a href='%s'>download</a>" % (self.files.url,)
        else:
            return "No attachment"

    file_link.allow_tags = True
    file_link.short_description = 'File Download'


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    student_ID = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=14,
                                  validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{14}$',
                                                             message='The ID needs to be 14 characters long.')],
                                  null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='students_images', null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True, default=None,
                             validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[a-zA-Z0-9+]+$',
                                                        message='Not a valid phone number.')], )
    file_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

```css
{% if user.is_student %}
                            {{ user.student.file_status }}
                            {% if user.student.file_status == False %}
                                <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    {{ form.as_p }}
                                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                                </form>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
```

```html
def courses(request, slug):
    query = Course.objects.get(slug=slug)
    data = request.POST.copy()
    data['course'] = query.id
    form = StudentFileForm(data, request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            upload = form.save(commit=False)
            upload.user = request.user
            upload.user.student.file_status = True
            print(upload.user.student.file_status)
            upload.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('courses:confirmation'))
    else:
        form = StudentFileForm(initial={'course': query.id})
    context = {'courses': Course.objects.filter(slug=slug),
               'students': Student.objects.all(),
               'students_data': StudentData.objects.all(),
               'lectures': query.lectures.order_by('lecture_category'),
               'form': form,
               'uploads': StudentFileUpload.objects.all(),
               }
    return render(request, 'courses/courses.html', context)

class StudentFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentFileUpload
        fields = ('course', 'files', 'comment')
        widgets = {
            'course': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
        exclude = ['user']
```

Comment: Your view seems OK. You are saving a form, I think the problem come from StudentFileForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the view code as I'm outlining here:

```
def courses(request, slug):
query = Course.objects.get(slug=slug)
data = request.POST.copy()
data['course'] = query.id
form = StudentFileForm(data, request.FILES)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        upload = form.save(commit=False)
        upload.user = request.user
        # you need to get the student object to be able to save it
        student = upload.user.student
        student.file_status = True
        student.save()
        upload.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('courses:confirmation'))
else:
    form = StudentFileForm(initial={'course': query.id})
context = {'courses': Course.objects.filter(slug=slug),
           'students': Student.objects.all(),
           'students_data': StudentData.objects.all(),
           'lectures': query.lectures.order_by('lecture_category'),
           'form': form,
           'uploads': StudentFileUpload.objects.all(),
           }
return render(request, 'courses/courses.html', context)
```

Comment: Works as intended!

Answer (score 0):

You are saving only "upload", so you only assign the user.id.
If you need to change the Student object, you should implicitly save it:
upload.user.student.save()

Comment: Nope. Still same result.

Comment: I printed it after saving, boolean remains False.

Comment: you may try upload.user.student.save(file_status = True)

Comment: then I get error: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file_status'